# How to test a service with multiple constructor parameters in NestJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, testing, jestjs, nestjs

## Background

When I'm testing a service that requires one parameter in the constructor, I have to initialize the service as a provider using an object rather than simply passing the service through as a provider:

**auth.service.ts** (example)

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Admin)
    private readonly adminRepository: Repository<Admin>,
  ) { }

  // ...

}
```

**auth.service.spec.ts** (example)

```
describe('AuthService', () => {
  let authService: AuthService


  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
        providers: [
          AuthService,
          {
            provide: getRepositoryToken(Admin),
            useValue: mockRepository,
          },
        ],
      }).compile()

    authService = module.get<AuthService>(AuthService)
  })

  // ...

})
```

See [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/363#issuecomment-360105413) for the source of this explanation.

---

## My issue

I have a service that requires 2 parameters in the constructor:

**auth.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private readonly jwtService: JwtService,
    private readonly authHelper: AuthHelper,
  ) {}

  // ...

}
```

**How do I initialize this service in the test environment?** I can't pass multiple values to `useValue` in the `providers` array. My `AuthService` constructor has 2 parameters and I need to pass them both in order for the test to work.

Here's my current (not working) setup:

**auth.service.spec.ts**

```
describe('AuthService', () => {
  let service: AuthService

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [AuthService],
    }).compile()

    service = module.get<AuthService>(AuthService)
  })

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined()
  })

  // ...

})
```

When I don't pass them in, I get the following error:

```
  ● AuthService › should be defined

    Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthService (?, AuthHelper). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the TestModule context.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply create an entry in the `providers` array for each provider that is injected in your `AuthService`'s constructor:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
  const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
    providers: [
      AuthService,
      {provide: JwtService, useValue: jwtServiceMock},
      {provide: AuthHelper, useValue: authHelperMock},
    ],
  }).compile()
```

The test util `Test.createTestingModule()` creates a module just like your `AppModule` and hence also has a `providers` array that is used for dependency injection.